# Is it possible to use built-in bridges or automatically request them for the tor daemon in Linux? (Not Tor Browser)

Tags: configuration, bridge, obfsproxy, obfs4

I want to use obfs4 proxy to connect tor through it. It is not a Tor Browser.
I know that Tor Browser provides options to use built-in bridges or request them online, but to use it in tor daemon I need to manually request them from `bridges.torproject.org` and copy them to `/etc/tor/torrc`. Maybe tor daemon has a built-in bridges? Or script to request them automatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, getting bridges from `bridges.torproject.org` automatically to torrc is not possible without some kind of automation. As for what can be done, you have these options:

- Make a program that solves captchas (you can use "captcha solving services" for that, just google it and you'll find a bunch of sites that can do that) for you and sets the bridges to torrc config for you.
- Get gmail or riseup (don't even bother) email and send an email to `bridges@torproject.org` through the script that parses the response and sets the bridges in the config.

Anyhow, you'll need to create a script like that yourself, since I've never heard of anything like that done before.

> Maybe tor daemon has a built-in bridges?

Sadly, no. It's a Tor Browser feature only.